# How can I use KVC Collection Operators for distinctUnionOfObjects in NSArray of NSDictionaries?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, distinct-values, kvc

I want to get the Collection of a Specific Property from an array dictionary which has an array of values. Following is my array `NSDictionaries`:

```
NSArray *arrGroupsFromServer= @[
    @{@"Id": @"7d1021ba-e9be-40c1-a0a1-ad2a2d185b74",@"Name": @"1",@"modifiedDate": @"2016-01-29T15:39:57.000Z",@"PupilIdCollection":@[@"1",@"2"]},
    @{@"Id": @"4d830b79-f447-4ad7-8de1-063acf3e242c",@"Name": @"2 TEST",@"modifiedDate": @"2016-01-29T15:39:57.000Z",@"PupilIdCollection":@[@"1",@"3"]},
    @{@"Id": @"e481987d-fde8-4a6b-8e05-73877065236d",@"Name": @"CQ",@"modifiedDate": @"2016-01-29T15:39:57.000Z",@"PupilIdCollection":@[@"1",@"4"]},
    @{@"Id": @"1a44989d-8b3f-4d8e-8c74-a09c893ca02d",@"Name": @"Intervention group Number",@"modifiedDate": @"2016-01-29T15:39:57.000Z",@"PupilIdCollection":@[@"1",@"5"]},
    @{@"Id": @"f10f2fe0-b575-450d-ad63-10d0e8fbe097",@"Name": @"EYFS Caterpillars",@"modifiedDate": @"2016-01-29T15:39:57.000Z",@"PupilIdCollection":@[@"1",@"6"]},
    @{@"Id": @"232168c1-73a4-4bbb-b9a2-58e6765e4b2c",@"Name": @"Guided Reading group",@"modifiedDate": @"2016-01-29T15:39:57.000Z",@"PupilIdCollection":@[@"1",@"6"]},
    @{@"Id": @"1e9b66f7-c4a7-4774-b062-ce23f587a319",@"Name": @"HfL",@"modifiedDate": @"2016-01-29T15:39:57.000Z",@"PupilIdCollection":@[@"1",@"7"]},
    @{@"Id": @"62d53fc5-1fbf-4ebe-bc52-d07ec2680c66",@"Name": @"Red Intervention group",@"modifiedDate": @"2016-01-29T15:39:57.000Z",@"PupilIdCollection":@[@"1",@"8"]},
    @{@"Id": @"a70e7429-996a-46ff-aff7-1e1bc5e17c3b",@"Name": @"SEN Green group",@"modifiedDate": @"2016-01-29T15:39:57.000Z",@"PupilIdCollection":@[@"1",@"9"]},
    @{@"Id": @"44441c6f-843b-4933-9191-1f3afb23b6cf",@"Name": @"STAT",@"modifiedDate": @"2016-01-29T15:39:57.000Z",@"PupilIdCollection":@[@"1",@"2"]},
    @{@"Id": @"04aedc28-4706-49a1-8bbd-9d58179cfd55",@"Name": @"TIST",@"modifiedDate": @"2016-01-29T15:39:57.000Z",@"PupilIdCollection":@[@"1",@"2"]},
    @{@"Id": @"c98f592e-4adc-4d9d-a484-ae5b417f11db",@"Name": @"Year 8",@"modifiedDate": @"2016-01-29T15:39:57.000Z",@"PupilIdCollection":@[@"1",@"2"]}
];
```

Now I want to collect the `PupilIdCollection` Property into one single array with the `DistintctUnion` of all the values as follows:

```
NSArray * PupilIdCollection=@[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9"];(e.g. Order doesn't matter)
```

I have tried it the following way:

```
NSArray *arrPupilsIdsFromServer = [arrGroupsFromServer valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.PupilIdCollection"];
```

But this only gives me different Objects of `PupilIdCollection` in an array of `arrPupilsIdsFromServer` rather than the one object with the array of all the values in one array as following:

[image: Screenshot]

I want something like the following in just one line of code in KVC:

```
NSArray * PupilIdCollection=PupilIdCollection=@[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9"];(e.g. Order doesn't matter);(e.g. Order doesn't matter)
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `@distinctUnionOfArrays` instead of the `@distinctUnionOfObjects`. This operator helps flattening hierarchies of collections, and merge sub-arrays. See the developer documentation for details.

For example, these lines (used on your very NSArray)

```
NSArray *arrPupilsIdsFromServer = [arrGroupsFromServer valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfArrays.PupilIdCollection"];
NSLog(@"\nPupil Ids From Server:%@", arrPupilsIdsFromServer);
```

Yield this output:

```
Pupil Ids From Server:(
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8,
9
)
```

Answer (score 0):

from wain's answer you can do it after getting the values of `PupilIdCollection` for example,

```
 NSArray *pupilIdCollection = [arrGroupsFromServer valueForKeyPath:@"PupilIdCollection"];
__block  NSMutableSet *mutableSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
 [pupilIdCollection enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    [mutableSet addObjectsFromArray:obj];
 }];
 pupilIdCollection = [mutableSet allObjects];
 NSLog(@"all objects-%@",pupilIdCollection);
```

Comment: written nicely and efficiently (even though there's no need for it - there is a KVC collection operator that does the work) however - the enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: method runs concurrently on the subarrays, and calls mutableSet AddObjectsFromArray: from several threads at once. As far as I know - NSMutableSet is NOT thread-safe, and you should better synchronise the assignments to the set.

Answer (score -1):

**Wain** has explained it very well. I too feel that it would be very difficult to achieve in a single line. You can create a single array for all those elements and then use `distinctUnionOfObjects`.

```
NSMutableArray *singleArray =[NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *d in arrGroupsFromServer) {
    [singleArray addObjectsFromArray:[d objectForKey:@"PupilIdCollection"]];
}
NSArray *pupilIdCollection = [singleArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];
```